# Interpolation Polynomials with Integer coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Suppose we have an ordered list of real values:
$$x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_N \in \mathbb R$$

Now if we consider the set in  $\mathbb R^{2}$ (ie with their  ordering index  as the first variable) :

$${\{(1,x_1),(2,x_2),(3,x_3),...,(n,x_n),...,(N,x_N)}\}$$

I have found that the formula used by the computer algebra system I use to produce a polynomial that serves as an interpolation for this set of data points must be:

$$p_N(n)=\left( -1 \right) ^{N}\sum _{k=0}^{N}{\frac {n \left( n-1 \right) !\,\left( -1 \right) ^{k}x_{{k}}}{ \left( n-N-1 \right) !\, \left( n-k\right) k!\, \left( N-k \right) !}}$$

For example a  set of 3 data points:
$${\{(0,x_0),(1,x_1),(2,x_2)}\}$$

would produce an interpolation of:
$$p_2(n)=\left( \frac{1}{2}\,x_{{2}}-x_{{1}}+\frac{1}{2}\,x_{{0}} \right) {n}^{2}+ \left( -\frac{1}{2}
\,x_{{2}}+2\,x_{{1}}-\frac{3}{2}\,x_{{0}} \right) n+x_{{0}}$$

So my question regarding this, is the following:

1) What would be the best way of writing the out the requisites for $p_N(n)$ to be assured as having a **specific number** of integer coefficients?

Additional non specific question:

I feel that this statistical method is not at all helpful (well, as far as the mathematical understanding is concerned as or furthering my insight into the data I am interpolating)and I was wondering if any methods of deduction for "likely to be accurate extrapolation" functions for an infinite subset of $\mathbb R^{2}$ could be possible?

Or put another way, what are the first characteristics I should consider if I were to observe a set of the polynomials that are produced in the aforementioned manner as I increase the cardinality of the subset ($N$), my firsts thoughts where to ask myself if these polynomials are odd or even functions, (which would effectively half the number of functions of consideration for a form that would be more reliable than a polynomial if it were empirical data I was attempting to model)  but is there any other properties that are equally as general? Even a good book reference on this subject will get the upvote here really.